# How to get chainlink price feed data for my national currency?

Tags: ether, chainlink, oracles, data-feeds

I am new to blockchain currently learning and exploring. I followed Patrick's tutorial and now in order to have hands-on I want to implement a [FundMe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umepbfKp5rI) smart contract but for my national currency instead of USD. I am not sure if the way I am approaching this problem is correct. The reason I am thinking this way is that I want to display amount on frontend in my currency instead of USD.
I tried finding address for my desired data feed on [chainlink](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses?network=ethereum&page=1&search=ETH%2F), but did not find anything. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This might or might be topical for you, but I just published few [Chainlink tutorials here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/), including how to get price feeds. However if there is no existing Chainlink price feed, then you need to fetch the price data using Chainlink HTTPS oracle - a bit expensive depending on the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Chainlink data feed not only provides price of multiple asset values in units of USD(like BTC/USD, ETH/USD) but also provides the price of multiple fiats in units of USD.

If you want to implement "fundme" in the currency of your nation, the `priceConverter` could use this calculation to convert ETH to the currency you want to use:

ETH value in unit of your currency = (amount of ETH) * (ETH price in USD) / (your nation's currency price in USD)
Please head to the [data feed address list](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses?network=ethereum&page=1) to find 2 necessary addresses for ETH/USD and (your national currency)/USD.

Please be noticed in sepolia there is no such data feed provided, but you can find them in mainnet.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried but could not find my nation's currency in that list. There are very limited currencies feeds

Comment: @doc what is your nation?

Comment: I am from Pakistan, so basically Im looking for PKR conversion.

Comment: I checked data feed for Fiat, and PKR is not there. There are only 8 feeds that are listed here https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses?network=ethereum&page=1&search=forex .